# Pass Data from UICollectionView in Swift 2

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, swift2

My problem is I would like to Pass data from my collection view to a new view (tableview- but I think it's not necessary info)

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let myVC = DetailsTableViewController()
    myVC.movieTitle = movies[indexPath.row].movieTitle!
    print (movies[indexPath.row].movieTitle!)
    performSegueWithIdentifier("DetailSegue", sender: reuseIdentifier)
}
```

Print is OK, but my movieTitle: String? will NIL on the DetailsViewController.

Help!

Answer (score 0):

`performSegueWithIdentifier` will instantiate an appropriate destination controller and present it. The `DetailsTableViewController` you have instantiated here as `myVC` is never shown. You have a couple of options for how to approach this:

If you want to use segues then trigger the segue in `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` and implement `prepareForSegue` to pass data to the destination view controller (a `destinationViewController` will be available on the `UIStoryboardSegue` passed to that method).

Alternately you could avoid using segues and present your `myVC` directly by pushing it onto your current navigation controller (if one exists you could call `self.navigationController.pushViewController(myVC, animated:true)`), presenting it as a modal, or whatever makes sense in your app.

Comment: my problem is when use prepareForSegue I can't use movies[indexPath.row].movieTitle! - I can pass data from tableview or simple view too, I only have problem when I would like to pass data from uicollectionview cell

Answer (score 0):

problem solved. thanks

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "DetailSegue" {
        let detailsVC = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailsTableViewController
        if let cell = sender as? UICollectionViewCell, indexPath = collectionView!.indexPathForCell(cell) {
    // use indexPath
            detailsVC.movieTitle = movies[indexPath.row].movieTitle!
        }
    }
}
```